# Array IndexoutOfBounds before receiving json values?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, uicollectionviewcell

Storing Array Values:
   Before receiving the json values its show error

```
 for (DicEtc in ArrCategory){
            CatDescription=[[DicCategory objectForKey:@"cat_description"] length ]!=0 ? [DicCategory objectForKey:@"cat_description"]:@"" ;
            [DicSeparation setObject:CatDescription forKey:@"cat_description"];
            [DicSeparation setObject:[[DicCategory objectForKey:@"name"] length ]!=0 ? [DicCategory objectForKey:@"name"]:@"" forKey:@"name"];
            [ArrName addObject:DicSeparation];

        }
```

Displaying the Array into the tableview Label:

```
cell.lbl_cell.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ArrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cat_description"]];
```

OUTPUT:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: Check for [ArrName count]>0  before loading to cell once?

Comment: i am storing json values inside the array ,when i open the screen its get crashed and giving error.its not running asynchronously i think so @Sujania

Comment: now i got it your Answer @Sujania thanks sister

Comment: Glad your issues is solved ..